# how to find server current datetime while uploading the file and downloading the file using php and mysql

Tags: php

how to find server current datetime while uploading the file and downloading the file using php and mysql

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the php functions time() and date():

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

Try these:
In PHP:

```
$t = time();
$d = date();
```

In Mysql:

```
now()
select now()
```